# Can you determine if a sphere is completely occluded by other spheres, given coordinates and radii?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

I have several (3 or 4) large-sized spheres with known radii ${r_L}$ and known coordinates. The spheres might overlap. I then add a small sphere with known coordinates and known radius ${r_S}$.

Is it possible to tell, just from the coordinates and radii, whether this small sphere will be completely contained within the union of the large spheres?

The easy case is when the small sphere is fully contained within a single large sphere, which occurs when the distance between their centres is less than ${r_L} - {r_S}$. If the distance is slightly larger, then the small sphere will be partially occluded by the large sphere. The difficulty is determining whether the bit that peeks out will then be occluded by another large sphere.

A Monte-Carlo approach might be to sample points within ${r_S}$ of the small sphere, and test whether these points are within or without the larger spheres, but I'm hoping for an analytical or faster solution.

[image: example]

Comment: added 3d tag. Please roll back if not suitable.

Comment: The part of the smaller sphere occluded by another sphere is a circle. So this is reduced to a (spherical) 2d problem of checking whether the sphere is covered by a given finite set of circles. Should be much more efficient than the Monte-Carlo method once you work out the kinks.

Comment: I like that approach... I'll come back and answer if I can figure it out.

Comment: @tomasz - could this also be approached by defining a half-space passing through each circle, and then determining if the sum of half-spaces covers all space?

Comment: @lewiso1: No, that would be much stronger. A sphere can be occluded even if its centre is not in any of the spheres occluding it, and that is still weaker than what you ask.

Comment: @lewiso1 could use halfspaces to describe each circle; i.e. the plane of the intersection.  If the halfspaces include the other (not target) spheres, then the target sphere is covered by the finite set of circles (that tomasz described) if and only if the target sphere is covered by the union of those corresponding halfspaces.  (Target sphere, not all space, though.)